# Form error htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given and no line

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-form

If I change the error to simple HTML, the error is gone.

```
{{Form::open(array('url'=>'')) . "" }}
                    <div class="basic-form">
```

and it goes on: (cannot paste more code here)

```
                        <div class="hsb-input-1">
                            {{Form::text('user_query', array('class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'I\'m looking for qualified personnel in ...')) }}
                        </div>

                        <div class="hsb-text-1">Language</div>

                        <div class="hsb-container">

                            <div class="hsb-select">
                            {{Form::select('selection', 
                                ['all'=> 'Select all', 
                                'c' => 'C/C++/C#', 
                                'html' => 'HTML/CSS/Design', 
                                'java'=> 'Java', 
                                'javascript'=>'Javascript', 
                                'php'=>'PHP', 
                                'python'=>'Python', 
                                'ruby'=>'Ruby', 
                                'xml'=>'XML/XSLT/Xquery', 
                                'fortran'=>'Fortran', 
                                'vb'=>'VB', 
                                'sql'=>'SQL', 
                                'abap'=>'ABAP', 
                                'oc'=>OC, 
                                'swift'=>'SWIFT'], 
                                all,
                                ['class' => 'form-control']) 
                            }}
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="hsb-submit">
                            {{Form::submit('Submit', array('class' => 'btn btn-default btn-block', 'id' => 'submit'))}}
                            <!--<input type="submit" name="search" class="btn btn-default btn-block" value="Search"> -->
                        </div>
                    </div>

                {{Form::close()}}
```

What can I do to correct the error message? I think I have a mistake in the form.

Comment: As you can read from your error message it says: `htmlentities()`, but in your posted code there is no `htmlentities()` function call! So locate the error and post the code which contains the function call.

Answer (score 1):

You use it in wrong way. The second argument for `text` is not array of options but value ([reference](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Html/FormBuilder.html#method_text)) so instead of:

```
{{Form::text('user_query', array('class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'I\'m looking for qualified personnel in ...')) }}
```

it should be rather:

```
{{Form::text('user_query', null, array('class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'I\'m looking for qualified personnel in ...')) }}
```